# "link" to 360 video - Virtual Reality?

Tags: video, hyperlink, virtual, 360-degrees

I'm wondering if there is anyway to achieve something like that . ..

If i'm shooting a short movie in 360 degres - to read with an oculus or an iphone by a google cardboard.

Is there a way to add some 'link' inside the video.

let's imagine  that when I 'turn' inside the video, to make appear different link inside the video, an on 'action click' on that, to play another video ?

What would be the path to follow  ? Any API that you know ? Javascript ? Visaul Basic ? other ?

Thank you for your recommendation guys :)